# Why doesn't my regex match the end of the string?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I'm trying to add `<p>` tags to user-generated text in place of line breaks.

Here is my code:

```
string.gsub(/(.*)[\n\r\Z$]+/, "<p>\\1</p>")
```

The replacement works exactly as expected for the first paragraph, but it only wraps the final block of text if I add an extra carriage return. It seems like the `\Z` and `$` are not matching as I expect them to.

What am I doing wrong?

This:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
\n
Vestibulum laoreet erat id quam.
```

Turns into this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p> 

Vestibulum laoreet erat id quam.
```

But this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
\n
Vestibulum laoreet erat id quam.
\n
```

Turns into this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p> 

<p>Vestibulum laoreet erat id quam.</p>
```

Comment: It's a Rails function. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Also, what happens with the second (empty) line? That is not clear.

Comment: Still not clear. You want to surround every line with the `p` tag unless the line consists only of white characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the regex

```
/\A((?:.|[\n\r])+)\Z/
```

And replace with `\\1`

Your current regex matches up to the last newline/carriage character in your input string and `\Z` is not even working. `$` is a literal character in a character class.

---

If you mean you wanted to wrap each line between `<p>` and `</p>`, then you can simply use:

```
/^(.+)$/
```

And replace with `\\1`

Or use the regex:

```
/([^\n\r]+)/
```

Comment: This wraps all text in one single `<p>`. Not multiple `p`s for each block of text.

Comment: @Emerson I think the behaviour of `.` and `^$` might be different on Ruby/Rails... Try the last regex and let me know, since it doesn't use any `.` or `^$`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
ary = [
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\nVestibulum laoreet erat id quam.",
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\nVestibulum laoreet erat id quam.\n"
]

puts ary.map{ |a| 
  a.scan(/.+$/).map{ |s| "<p>#{s}</p>" } 
}
# >> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
# >> <p>Vestibulum laoreet erat id quam.</p>
# >> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
# >> <p>Vestibulum laoreet erat id quam.</p>
```

Both strings are returned the same way.

Regular expressions are not a magic wand you can wave to fix every problem. They have their uses, but too many people think that they're the right tool for most of their problems, and they're not. Also, people think that the more complex the pattern, the more likely it is that it'll fix the problem, but instead the complexity provides more places for junk to squish out, so keep them simple.

This code:

```
a.scan(/.+$/).map{ |s| "<p>#{s}</p>" }
```

Relies on String's [`scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-scan) to look through a string and return all "\n" terminated lines. If the line doesn't end with "\n" it gets returned also because it's the final part of the string. [`scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-scan) returns an array of matches, so, in this particular situation, that'd be an array of string fragments terminated by the EOL with a possible trailing string-fragment.

Pass those through a [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to embed the string-fragment inside `<p>...</p>` and you're done.

An alternate way to accomplish the same thing is to take advantage of String's [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a block:

```
puts ary.map{ |a| 
  a.gsub(/.+$/) { |s| "<p>#{s}</p>" }
}
# >> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
# >> <p>Vestibulum laoreet erat id quam.</p>
# >> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
# >> <p>Vestibulum laoreet erat id quam.</p>
```

For each instance that matches the pattern, [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) will pass the matched text to the block. From there it's another simple string interpolation.